# Do I want to use Remoting or just a Socket connection

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, remoting

I'm writing code for a project that was initially written in VB6 and my partner and I are trying to slowly migrate it to .NET. In the mean time I need some feedback on how I should go about doing the following:

My users can run several instances the same program to help split several specific Messages sent to a server; a server that will IP Ban you if you send to many messages at one time. What I want to do is share these messages sent between the programs so that we can build a distributed messaging system to prevent an IP Ban - these programs are running on the same machine at the present. I'm trying to get my feet wet, so I've done *several* (no joke...) days worth of research and I came to the conclusion that I could write a DLL in C# .NET, incorporate the needed Interop to support COM, and have that DLL store commonly used Functions, Arrays, Etc. The function would also raise events on the VB6 program to send its messages which then the client program would send to the server its connected to.

My partner says I'm going about this the wrong way and that I should to create a Sever application that loads when the first stances of my program starts and distribute messages between my clients via Socket. This process seems like a lot of work.

I'm finding it all the more difficult because samples I've found on MSDN won't compile. If you know of a great example I'd really appreciate you posting it.

Comment: This wouldn't have anything to do with Battle.net would it? :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Remoting for new development. It has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Use WCF instead. You can host a WCF service in any application, and it can communicate quite quickly and efficiently using binary over TCP/IP.